# document.ready working only once on page load

Tags: javascript, templates

I have the following code in a .tpl file ("comment_form.tpl"). This file is included in 3 different .tpl files ("file_a", "file_b" and "file_c") once each. And finally these 3 files are included in another .tpl file ("somefile.tpl").

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function Hide() {
    document.getElementById('div').style.display = 'none';
</script>
```

So basically, the "comment_form.tpl" is loaded  thrice in "somefile.tpl" like so:

```
        .....
    </div><!-- .span9 -->
    {include file="includes/file_a.tpl"} // includes "file_a.tpl" which already includes "comment_form.tpl" (which contains the code).
    </div>
   .....//some code

   {include file="includes/file_b.tpl.tpl"} // "includes file_b.tpl" which already includes "comment_form.tpl" (which contains the code).
```

The issue is, the code works the first time. As in, out of the three places where the "comment_form.tpl" is loaded in "somefile.tpl", the target 'div' is hidden only the first time. At the next two places the form (div) isn't hidden.
I hope I am clear enough. What could be the reason??

Comment: If you're including some content that results in an "id" value being re-used, that's the problem.

Comment: so whats the solution? I cant have three different ids for the same div...

Comment: It's not the same `<div>` if it appears three times in the document. That's just how things work. Use a class instead, or have your template code synthesize unique "id" values dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly legal to have multiple `$(document).ready(function() {})` calls throughout your page.

It seems that you are hiding your element **by ID**. Note that IDs *must* be unique, and if you use the same ID multiple times (`#div` in your example), *only ever the first* is selected by `getElementById()`. That's what you are experiencing.

You must give each `<div>` a unique ID or group them together with a CSS class and hide the whole class.

Here is an example using a CSS class:

```
<div class="comment_form">some content</div>
<div class="comment_form">some content</div>
<div class="comment_form">some content</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.comment_form').css({'display' : 'none'});
}
</script>
```

By the way it's far more efficient to directly use CSS for the initial 'hidden' state of your `<div>`. There is no need to execute JavaScript on page load at all:

```
<style>
.comment_form { display: none; }
</style>
<div class="comment_form">some content</div>
```

You can still change the `display` property of your element later via JavaScript in an `onClick` event, for example.

Comment: the reason why I am having to use js initially is cuz the css doesnt fill the space... as in the div is hidden but a blank space is left. The rest of the html follows after the space.

Comment: The problem with this is that all the divs will toggle together. I need specific divs to show/hide.

Comment: @stylojack_10 then you need to generate specific IDs for each DIV to toggle.